# EXIF Data LensModel property

Tags: jquery, exif

I'm using below jQuery plugin to retrieve EXIF data from images

```
https://github.com/sanisoft/jQuery-fileExif/blob/master/jquery.exif.js
```

However there is no code in this to retrieve lens model data.

So I added the code

```
0xA434 : "LensModel",
```

after line 315 `(0xA40C : "SubjectDistanceRange", )`

But even if I try to retrieve it is coming back blank.

```
exifObject.LensModel
```

You can see a example here

https://jsfiddle.net/Lx4wdkhw/

You can use below image that have lens meta tag

https://www.flickr.com/photos/138863932@N02/29888704290/

Can someone point me out what I'm doing wrong here. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you check that the image actually contains a Lens Model? Not all images do. You can use `jhead` on your local machine to check.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes i did. It is there. All other tags are coming up fine.

Comment: Can you make am image available with it in please?

Comment: can you create a [mcve] into a fiddle?

Comment: @ochi added a example.

Comment: @MarkSetchell i added a example and photo url that have a photo with all the data.

Comment: How can I download the file to my local machine?

Comment: @MarkSetchell you mean the image file? You use this link https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5636/29888704290_78aae5380b_o_d.jpg

Comment: Do you have to use this particular plugin?  I found a way to accomplish what you did using a different JS library (https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js) - see running **fiddle here**: https://jsfiddle.net/t3k59cgq/1/ - If using this library is OK with you, I'll post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if using a different library is OK with you.  I found out that not all libraries are able to read the properties correctly.

I played around with this library: https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js and added the code for `LensModel` just like you did, but under the `EXIF.TiffTags`:

```
var TiffTags = EXIF.TiffTags = {
   ...
   0xA434 : "LensModel",
   ...
}
```

Then, I was able to read the property correctly, **see running demo below**:

```js
(function(){function e(e){return!!e.exifdata}function t(e,t){t=t||e.match(/^data\:([^\;]+)\;base64,/im)[1]||"",e=e.replace(/^data\:([^\;]+)\;base64,/gim,"");for(var n=atob(e),r=n.length,o=new ArrayBuffer(r),i=new Uint8Array(o),a=0;r>a;a++)i[a]=n.charCodeAt(a);return o}function r(e,t){var n=new XMLHttpRequest;n.open("GET",e,!0),n.responseType="blob",n.onload=function(e){(200==this.status||0===this.status)&&t(this.response)},n.send()}function o(e,n){function o(t){var r=i(t),o=a(t);e.exifdata=r||{},e.iptcdata=o||{},n&&n.call(e)}if(e.src)if(/^data\:/i.test(e.src)){var s=t(e.src);o(s)}else if(/^blob\:/i.test(e.src)){var l=new FileReader;l.onload=function(e){o(e.target.result)},r(e.src,function(e){l.readAsArrayBuffer(e)})}else{var u=new XMLHttpRequest;u.onload=function(){if(200!=this.status&&0!==this.status)throw"Could not load image";o(u.response),u=null},u.open("GET",e.src,!0),u.responseType="arraybuffer",u.send(null)}else if(window.FileReader&&(e instanceof window.Blob||e instanceof window.File)){var l=new FileReader;l.onload=function(e){f&&console.log("Got file of length "+e.target.result.byteLength),o(e.target.result)},l.readAsArrayBuffer(e)}}function i(e){var t=new DataView(e);if(f&&console.log("Got file of length "+e.byteLength),255!=t.getUint8(0)||216!=t.getUint8(1))return f&&console.log("Not a valid JPEG"),!1;for(var n,r=2,o=e.byteLength;o>r;){if(255!=t.getUint8(r))return f&&console.log("Not a valid marker at offset "+r+", found: "+t.getUint8(r)),!1;if(n=t.getUint8(r+1),f&&console.log(n),225==n)return f&&console.log("Found 0xFFE1 marker"),c(t,r+4,t.getUint16(r+2)-2);r+=2+t.getUint16(r+2)}}function a(e){var t=new DataView(e);if(f&&console.log("Got file of length "+e.byteLength),255!=t.getUint8(0)||216!=t.getUint8(1))return f&&console.log("Not a valid JPEG"),!1;for(var n=2,r=e.byteLength,o=function(e,t){return 56===e.getUint8(t)&&66===e.getUint8(t+1)&&73===e.getUint8(t+2)&&77===e.getUint8(t+3)&&4===e.getUint8(t+4)&&4===e.getUint8(t+5)};r>n;){if(o(t,n)){var i=t.getUint8(n+7);i%2!==0&&(i+=1),0===i&&(i=4);var a=n+8+i,l=t.getUint16(n+6+i);return s(e,a,l)}n++}}function s(e,t,n){for(var r,o,i,a,s,l=new DataView(e),u={},c=t;t+n>c;)28===l.getUint8(c)&&2===l.getUint8(c+1)&&(a=l.getUint8(c+2),a in F&&(i=l.getInt16(c+3),s=i+5,o=F[a],r=d(l,c+5,i),u.hasOwnProperty(o)?u[o]instanceof Array?u[o].push(r):u[o]=[u[o],r]:u[o]=r)),c++;return u}function l(e,t,n,r,o){var i,a,s,l=e.getUint16(n,!o),d={};for(s=0;l>s;s++)i=n+12*s+2,a=r[e.getUint16(i,!o)],!a&&f&&console.log("Unknown tag: "+e.getUint16(i,!o)),d[a]=u(e,i,t,n,o);return d}function u(e,t,n,r,o){var i,a,s,l,u,c,f=e.getUint16(t+2,!o),g=e.getUint32(t+4,!o),h=e.getUint32(t+8,!o)+n;switch(f){case 1:case 7:if(1==g)return e.getUint8(t+8,!o);for(i=g>4?h:t+8,a=[],l=0;g>l;l++)a[l]=e.getUint8(i+l);return a;case 2:return i=g>4?h:t+8,d(e,i,g-1);case 3:if(1==g)return e.getUint16(t+8,!o);for(i=g>2?h:t+8,a=[],l=0;g>l;l++)a[l]=e.getUint16(i+2*l,!o);return a;case 4:if(1==g)return e.getUint32(t+8,!o);for(a=[],l=0;g>l;l++)a[l]=e.getUint32(h+4*l,!o);return a;case 5:if(1==g)return u=e.getUint32(h,!o),c=e.getUint32(h+4,!o),s=new Number(u/c),s.numerator=u,s.denominator=c,s;for(a=[],l=0;g>l;l++)u=e.getUint32(h+8*l,!o),c=e.getUint32(h+4+8*l,!o),a[l]=new Number(u/c),a[l].numerator=u,a[l].denominator=c;return a;case 9:if(1==g)return e.getInt32(t+8,!o);for(a=[],l=0;g>l;l++)a[l]=e.getInt32(h+4*l,!o);return a;case 10:if(1==g)return e.getInt32(h,!o)/e.getInt32(h+4,!o);for(a=[],l=0;g>l;l++)a[l]=e.getInt32(h+8*l,!o)/e.getInt32(h+4+8*l,!o);return a}}function d(e,t,r){var o="";for(n=t;n<t+r;n++)o+=String.fromCharCode(e.getUint8(n));return o}function c(e,t){if("Exif"!=d(e,t,4))return f&&console.log("Not valid EXIF data! "+d(e,t,4)),!1;var n,r,o,i,a,s=t+6;if(18761==e.getUint16(s))n=!1;else{if(19789!=e.getUint16(s))return f&&console.log("Not valid TIFF data! (no 0x4949 or 0x4D4D)"),!1;n=!0}if(42!=e.getUint16(s+2,!n))return f&&console.log("Not valid TIFF data! (no 0x002A)"),!1;var u=e.getUint32(s+4,!n);if(8>u)return f&&console.log("Not valid TIFF data! (First offset less than 8)",e.getUint32(s+4,!n)),!1;if(r=l(e,s,s+u,p,n),r.ExifIFDPointer){i=l(e,s,s+r.ExifIFDPointer,m,n);for(o in i){switch(o){case"LightSource":case"Flash":case"MeteringMode":case"ExposureProgram":case"SensingMethod":case"SceneCaptureType":case"SceneType":case"CustomRendered":case"WhiteBalance":case"GainControl":case"Contrast":case"Saturation":case"Sharpness":case"SubjectDistanceRange":case"FileSource":i[o]=P[o][i[o]];break;case"ExifVersion":case"FlashpixVersion":i[o]=String.fromCharCode(i[o][0],i[o][1],i[o][2],i[o][3]);break;case"ComponentsConfiguration":i[o]=P.Components[i[o][0]]+P.Components[i[o][1]]+P.Components[i[o][2]]+P.Components[i[o][3]]}r[o]=i[o]}}if(r.GPSInfoIFDPointer){a=l(e,s,s+r.GPSInfoIFDPointer,S,n);for(o in a){switch(o){case"GPSVersionID":a[o]=a[o][0]+"."+a[o][1]+"."+a[o][2]+"."+a[o][3]}r[o]=a[o]}}return r}var f=!1,g=this,h=function(e){return e instanceof h?e:this instanceof h?void(this.EXIFwrapped=e):new h(e)};"undefined"!=typeof exports?("undefined"!=typeof module&&module.exports&&(exports=module.exports=h),exports.EXIF=h):g.EXIF=h;var m=h.Tags={36864:"ExifVersion",40960:"FlashpixVersion",40961:"ColorSpace",40962:"PixelXDimension",40963:"PixelYDimension",37121:"ComponentsConfiguration",37122:"CompressedBitsPerPixel",37500:"MakerNote",37510:"UserComment",40964:"RelatedSoundFile",36867:"DateTimeOriginal",36868:"DateTimeDigitized",37520:"SubsecTime",37521:"SubsecTimeOriginal",37522:"SubsecTimeDigitized",33434:"ExposureTime",33437:"FNumber",34850:"ExposureProgram",34852:"SpectralSensitivity",34855:"ISOSpeedRatings",34856:"OECF",37377:"ShutterSpeedValue",37378:"ApertureValue",37379:"BrightnessValue",37380:"ExposureBias",37381:"MaxApertureValue",37382:"SubjectDistance",37383:"MeteringMode",37384:"LightSource",37385:"Flash",37396:"SubjectArea",37386:"FocalLength",41483:"FlashEnergy",41484:"SpatialFrequencyResponse",41486:"FocalPlaneXResolution",41487:"FocalPlaneYResolution",41488:"FocalPlaneResolutionUnit",41492:"SubjectLocation",41493:"ExposureIndex",41495:"SensingMethod",41728:"FileSource",41729:"SceneType",41730:"CFAPattern",41985:"CustomRendered",41986:"ExposureMode",41987:"WhiteBalance",41988:"DigitalZoomRation",41989:"FocalLengthIn35mmFilm",41990:"SceneCaptureType",41991:"GainControl",41992:"Contrast",41993:"Saturation",41994:"Sharpness",41995:"DeviceSettingDescription",41996:"SubjectDistanceRange",40965:"InteroperabilityIFDPointer",42016:"ImageUniqueID"},p=h.TiffTags={256:"ImageWidth",257:"ImageHeight",34665:"ExifIFDPointer",34853:"GPSInfoIFDPointer",40965:"InteroperabilityIFDPointer",258:"BitsPerSample",259:"Compression",262:"PhotometricInterpretation",274:"Orientation",277:"SamplesPerPixel",284:"PlanarConfiguration",530:"YCbCrSubSampling",531:"YCbCrPositioning",282:"XResolution",283:"YResolution",296:"ResolutionUnit",273:"StripOffsets",278:"RowsPerStrip",279:"StripByteCounts",513:"JPEGInterchangeFormat",514:"JPEGInterchangeFormatLength",301:"TransferFunction",318:"WhitePoint",319:"PrimaryChromaticities",529:"YCbCrCoefficients",532:"ReferenceBlackWhite",306:"DateTime",270:"ImageDescription",271:"Make",272:"Model",305:"Software",315:"Artist",42036:"LensModel",33432:"Copyright"},S=h.GPSTags={0:"GPSVersionID",1:"GPSLatitudeRef",2:"GPSLatitude",3:"GPSLongitudeRef",4:"GPSLongitude",5:"GPSAltitudeRef",6:"GPSAltitude",7:"GPSTimeStamp",8:"GPSSatellites",9:"GPSStatus",10:"GPSMeasureMode",11:"GPSDOP",12:"GPSSpeedRef",13:"GPSSpeed",14:"GPSTrackRef",15:"GPSTrack",16:"GPSImgDirectionRef",17:"GPSImgDirection",18:"GPSMapDatum",19:"GPSDestLatitudeRef",20:"GPSDestLatitude",21:"GPSDestLongitudeRef",22:"GPSDestLongitude",23:"GPSDestBearingRef",24:"GPSDestBearing",25:"GPSDestDistanceRef",26:"GPSDestDistance",27:"GPSProcessingMethod",28:"GPSAreaInformation",29:"GPSDateStamp",30:"GPSDifferential"},P=h.StringValues={ExposureProgram:{0:"Not defined",1:"Manual",2:"Normal program",3:"Aperture priority",4:"Shutter priority",5:"Creative program",6:"Action program",7:"Portrait mode",8:"Landscape mode"},MeteringMode:{0:"Unknown",1:"Average",2:"CenterWeightedAverage",3:"Spot",4:"MultiSpot",5:"Pattern",6:"Partial",255:"Other"},LightSource:{0:"Unknown",1:"Daylight",2:"Fluorescent",3:"Tungsten (incandescent light)",4:"Flash",9:"Fine weather",10:"Cloudy weather",11:"Shade",12:"Daylight fluorescent (D 5700 - 7100K)",13:"Day white fluorescent (N 4600 - 5400K)",14:"Cool white fluorescent (W 3900 - 4500K)",15:"White fluorescent (WW 3200 - 3700K)",17:"Standard light A",18:"Standard light B",19:"Standard light C",20:"D55",21:"D65",22:"D75",23:"D50",24:"ISO studio tungsten",255:"Other"},Flash:{0:"Flash did not fire",1:"Flash fired",5:"Strobe return light not detected",7:"Strobe return light detected",9:"Flash fired, compulsory flash mode",13:"Flash fired, compulsory flash mode, return light not detected",15:"Flash fired, compulsory flash mode, return light detected",16:"Flash did not fire, compulsory flash mode",24:"Flash did not fire, auto mode",25:"Flash fired, auto mode",29:"Flash fired, auto mode, return light not detected",31:"Flash fired, auto mode, return light detected",32:"No flash function",65:"Flash fired, red-eye reduction mode",69:"Flash fired, red-eye reduction mode, return light not detected",71:"Flash fired, red-eye reduction mode, return light detected",73:"Flash fired, compulsory flash mode, red-eye reduction mode",77:"Flash fired, compulsory flash mode, red-eye reduction mode, return light not detected",79:"Flash fired, compulsory flash mode, red-eye reduction mode, return light detected",89:"Flash fired, auto mode, red-eye reduction mode",93:"Flash fired, auto mode, return light not detected, red-eye reduction mode",95:"Flash fired, auto mode, return light detected, red-eye reduction mode"},SensingMethod:{1:"Not defined",2:"One-chip color area sensor",3:"Two-chip color area sensor",4:"Three-chip color area sensor",5:"Color sequential area sensor",7:"Trilinear sensor",8:"Color sequential linear sensor"},SceneCaptureType:{0:"Standard",1:"Landscape",2:"Portrait",3:"Night scene"},SceneType:{1:"Directly photographed"},CustomRendered:{0:"Normal process",1:"Custom process"},WhiteBalance:{0:"Auto white balance",1:"Manual white balance"},GainControl:{0:"None",1:"Low gain up",2:"High gain up",3:"Low gain down",4:"High gain down"},Contrast:{0:"Normal",1:"Soft",2:"Hard"},Saturation:{0:"Normal",1:"Low saturation",2:"High saturation"},Sharpness:{0:"Normal",1:"Soft",2:"Hard"},SubjectDistanceRange:{0:"Unknown",1:"Macro",2:"Close view",3:"Distant view"},FileSource:{3:"DSC"},Components:{0:"",1:"Y",2:"Cb",3:"Cr",4:"R",5:"G",6:"B"}},F={120:"caption",110:"credit",25:"keywords",55:"dateCreated",80:"byline",85:"bylineTitle",122:"captionWriter",105:"headline",116:"copyright",15:"category"};h.getData=function(t,n){return(t instanceof Image||t instanceof HTMLImageElement)&&!t.complete?!1:(e(t)?n&&n.call(t):o(t,n),!0)},h.getTag=function(t,n){return e(t)?t.exifdata[n]:void 0},h.getAllTags=function(t){if(!e(t))return{};var n,r=t.exifdata,o={};for(n in r)r.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(o[n]=r[n]);return o},h.pretty=function(t){if(!e(t))return"";var n,r=t.exifdata,o="";for(n in r)r.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(o+="object"==typeof r[n]?r[n]instanceof Number?n+" : "+r[n]+" ["+r[n].numerator+"/"+r[n].denominator+"]\r\n":n+" : ["+r[n].length+" values]\r\n":n+" : "+r[n]+"\r\n");return o},h.readFromBinaryFile=function(e){return i(e)},"function"==typeof define&&define.amd&&define("exif-js",[],function(){return h})}).call(this);

$(function() {
  $('#file').on('change', function(e) {
    EXIF.getData(e.target.files[0], function() {
      //console.log(EXIF.pretty(this));      
      var make = EXIF.getTag(this, "Make");
      var model = EXIF.getTag(this, "Model");
      var lensModel = EXIF.getTag(this, "LensModel");
      
      console.log("Make: " + make);
      console.log("Make: " + model);
      console.log("LensModel: " + lensModel);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="file" id="file" />
</form>
```

Comment: glad I could help :)

Comment: which data we need to pass in  EXIF.getData(e.target.files[0], function() {} ); 
means i am not getting any result when i am passing image url as e.target.files[0] ,
so what we need to pass as e.target.files[0]  ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for me. I get `undefined` for the lens. It is ok for the camera.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit if you create a [mre] in a new question, we might be able to help with your specific issue

Comment: @GaurangSondagar if you create a [mre] in a new question, we might be able to help with your specific issue.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Answer**

As I guessed in my original answer below, the `LensModel` is not in the section you expect, it is in the `TIFF` section. You need to put the tag you are looking for in `EXIF.TiffTags[]`:

```
  EXIF.TiffTags = {
  0x0100: "ImageWidth",
  0x0101: "ImageHeight",
  0xA434: "LensModel",               <--- ### HERE ###
  0x8769: "ExifIFDPointer",
  0x8825: "GPSInfoIFDPointer",
```

**Original Answer**

Not a complete answer, but may help you, or someone else work it out... if you run `jhead` on your image, the `LensModel` tag doesn't appear to be in the EXIF section, which has 32 entries starting with:

```
    Exif Dir:(dir has 32 entries)
        ExposureTime = 1/4000
```

and ending with:

```
        Unknown Tag ea1c Value = "?Í?"
        Unknown Tag ea1d Value = 2010
```

It seems to be in a subsequent section.

Here it is in full:

```
JFIF SOI marker: Units: 1 (dots per inch)  X-density=72 Y-density=72
Exif header 12234 bytes long
Exif section in Motorola order
(dir has 21 entries)
    Make = "Canon"
    Model = "Canon EOS REBEL T5"
    Orientation = 1
    DateTime = "2014:01:31 03:22:41"
    Artist = ""
    YCbCrPositioning = 2
    Unknown Tag 4746 Value = 0
    Unknown Tag 4749 Value = 0
    Copyright = ""
    ExifOffset = 2372
    Exif Dir:(dir has 32 entries)
        ExposureTime = 1/4000
        FNumber = 35/10
        ExposureProgram = 3
        ISOSpeedRatings = 100
        ExifVersion = "0230"
        DateTimeOriginal = "2014:01:31 03:22:41"
        DateTimeDigitized = "2014:01:31 03:22:41"
        ComponentsConfiguration = "?"
        ShutterSpeedValue = 786432/65536
        ApertureValue = 237568/65536
        ExposureBiasValue = 0/1
        MeteringMode = 5
        Flash = 16
        FocalLength = 18/1
        Maker note: (dir has 37 entries)
            Canon maker tag 0001 Value = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
            Canon maker tag 0002 Value = 0, 0, 0, 0
            Canon maker tag 0003 Value = 0, 0, 0, 0
            Canon maker tag 0004 Value = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
            Canon maker tag 0006 Value = ""
            Canon maker tag 0007 Value = ""
            Canon maker tag 0009 Value = ""
            Canon maker tag 000d Value = "CanonCanon EOS REBEL T52014:01:31 03:22:41 Çö÷Çùﬁà"à'dê0230êÊê˙ëíííííí&í|.íÜ.>íê00Líë00íí00†0100††@†Ä¢/F¢/N¢§^§^§§Í Í⁄Í"
            Canon maker tag 0010 Value = -2147482841
            Canon maker tag 0013 Value = 0, 0, 0, 0
            Canon maker tag 0019 Value = 1
            Canon maker tag 0026 Value = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
            Canon maker tag 0035 Value = 0, 0, 0, 0
            Canon maker tag 0093 Value = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
            Canon maker tag 0095 Value = ""
            Canon maker tag 0096 Value = ""
            Canon maker tag 0097 Value = ""
            Canon maker tag 0098 Value = 0, 0, 0, 0
            Canon maker tag 0099 Value = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
            Canon maker tag 009a Value = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
            Canon maker tag 00a0 Value = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
            Canon maker tag 00aa Value = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
            Canon maker tag 00b4 Value = 1
            Canon maker tag 00d0 Value = 0
            Canon maker tag 00e0 Value = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
            Canon maker tag 4001 Value = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
            Canon maker tag 4008 Value = 0, 0, 0
            Canon maker tag 4009 Value = 0, 0, 0
            Canon maker tag 4010 Value = "ˇˇˇˇó∂q"
            Canon maker tag 4011 Value = "ˇˇEF-S18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS IIME0422512"
            Canon maker tag 4012 Value = ""
            Canon maker tag 4015 Value = ""
            Canon maker tag 4016 Value = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
            Canon maker tag 4017 Value = 0, 0
            Canon maker tag 4018 Value = 0, 0, 0
            Canon maker tag 4019 Value = ""
            Canon maker tag 4020 Value = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        UserComment = "?"
        SubSecTime = "00"
        SubSecTimeOriginal = "00"
        SubSecTimeDigitized = "00"
        FlashPixVersion = "0100"
        ColorSpace = 1
        ExifImageWidth = 5184
        ExifImageLength = 3456
        FocalPlaneXResolution = 5184000/905
        FocalPlaneYResolution = 3456000/595
        FocalPlaneResolutionUnit = 2
        CustomRendered = 0
        ExposureMode = 0
        WhiteBalance = 0
        SceneCaptureType = 0
        Unknown Tag ea1c Value = "?Í?"
        Unknown Tag ea1d Value = 2010
    GPS Dir offset = 12120
    GPS info dir:(dir has 1 entries)
        GPSVersionID        =""
    Unknown Tag 8830 Value = 2
    Unknown Tag 8832 Value = 100
    Windows-XP author = 
    Unknown Tag a430 Value = ""
    Unknown Tag a431 Value = "282074049031"
    Unknown Tag a432 Value = 18/1, 55/1, 0/0, 0/0
    Unknown Tag a434 Value = "EF-S18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS II"   <--- HERE IT IS
    Unknown Tag a435 Value = "00003bd8e5"
    Unknown Tag ea1c Value = "?Í?"
    Unknown Tag ea1d Value = 4118
Image cotains XMP section, 3193 bytes long
?yhttp://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/?<?xpacket begin='???' id='W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d'?>?
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/"><rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
><rdf:Description rdf:about="uuid:faf5bdd5-ba3d-11da-ad31-d33d75182f1b" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.c
om/xap/1.0/"><xmp:Rating>0</xmp:Rating><xmp:CreateDate>2014-01-31T03:22:41</xmp:CreateDate></rdf:Des
cription><rdf:Description rdf:about="uuid:faf5bdd5-ba3d-11da-ad31-d33d75182f1b" xmlns:MicrosoftPhoto
="http://ns.microsoft.com/photo/1.0/"><MicrosoftPhoto:Rating>0</MicrosoftPhoto:Rating></rdf:Descript
ion><rdf:Description rdf:about="uuid:faf5bdd5-ba3d-11da-ad31-d33d75182f1b" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org
/dc/elements/1.1/"/><rdf:Description rdf:about="uuid:faf5bdd5-ba3d-11da-ad31-d33d75182f1b" xmlns:dc=
"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"><dc:rights><rdf:Alt xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-s
yntax-ns#"><rdf:li xml:lang="x-default"></rdf:li></rdf:Alt>?
???</dc:rights><dc:creator><rdf:Seq xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"><rdf:li>
</rdf:li></rdf:Seq>?
???</dc:creator></rdf:Description></rdf:RDF></x:xmpmeta>?

Approximate quality factor for qtable 0: 98 (scale 4.64, var 2.36)
Approximate quality factor for qtable 1: 98 (scale 4.14, var 0.14)
JPEG image is 3888w * 2474h, 3 color components, 8 bits per sample
File name    : 29888704290_78aae5380b_o.jpg
File size    : 3584942 bytes
File date    : 2016:10:08 07:12:04
Camera make  : Canon
Camera model : Canon EOS REBEL T5
Date/Time    : 2014:01:31 03:22:41
Resolution   : 3888 x 2474
Flash used   : No
Focal length : 18.0mm  (35mm equivalent: 28mm)
CCD width    : 22.99mm
Exposure time: 0.0003 s  (1/4000)
Aperture     : f/3.5
ISO equiv.   : 100
Whitebalance : Auto
Metering Mode: pattern
Exposure     : aperture priority (semi-auto)
GPS Latitude : ? ?
GPS Longitude: ? ?
```

Comment: Thank you. Im not sure where in the JavaScript to apply this, Would you mind pointing out.